# Saving QListWidget items using pushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I've created a playlist using QListWidget. Now I want to save this list using one pushButton, henceforth I can create or delete playlists. Also, how can I list out the saved/existing lists.

Answer (score 1):

With `QListWidget::items` you get a list of all items in `QListWidget`. Then with `QListWidgetItem::write` you write them into the stream associated with file.

When reading first create a list of `QListWidgetItem`'s and use `read` method.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is how do you want to save those data?
`QListWidgetItem::write` will use binary format specific for Qt.

If you have a playlist it would be best to use some data format which is widely used. For example [PLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_%28file_format%29) or [ASR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Stream_Redirector).